# Freeing Local References in android JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk

In the jni layer of the android code that I have written, am returning an array from the jni layer to the java layer. I am using DeleteLocalRef() to free the local reference before passing the result. i just wanted to make sure that the code i have written is proper. Please find the code below.Any help is appreciated.

```
extern "C"
{
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_com_jni_btRead(JNIEnv* env, jobject)
{

    unsigned char* reply = btRead();

    jbyteArray jba;
    if(reply)
    {       
        jba = env->NewByteArray(2048);
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(jba, 0, 2048, reinterpret_cast<jbyte*>(reply));
    }
    else
    {       
        jba = env->NewByteArray(0);
    }

    env->DeleteLocalRef(jba);
    return jba;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local variables are always created in stack segment and hence destroyed after returning from function. This diagram may help.

[image: Local variable assignment]

Answer (score 0):

A quote from [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html):

> A local reference is valid only within the dynamic context of the
>   native method that creates it, and only within that one invocation of
>   the native method. All local references created during the execution
>   of a native method will be freed once the native method returns.

So you may not free your local reference as it gets freed automatically.

Comment: Actually you can free them. And you should if you are creating a lot of them (for example in some loop), because by default you get only 16 of them (you can increase that with EnsureLocalCapacity method). Quote from here( (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/refs.html): "The Java virtual machine frees them for you when the native method returns to the caller. However, there are times when you, the JNI programmer, should explicitly free local references in order to avoid excessive memory usage. Consider the following situations..."